# How to wait a few seconds on a redirect in sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I want to wait a few seconds on the erb answerdoorno before it redirects to police how do  i do that having problems finding the answer....

```
post '/answerdoor' do 

    answerdoor = params[:door]  

    door = rand(2).floor
    if answerdoor.include?('yes') && door == 0

        erb :answerdoor, :locals => {:answerdoor => "You Decide to get up and answer the door", :answerdoor2 => " You are in Luck It's Your good buddy Dave." }

    elsif  answerdoor.include?('yes') && door == 1

        erb :answerdoor, :locals => {:answerdoor => "You Decide to get up and answer the door", :answerdoor2 => " Oh No its The cops." }
        redirect to ('/police')

    elsif answerdoor.include?('no') && door == 0

        erb :answerdoorno, :locals => {:answerdoor => "You Decide not to answer the door, but it dosen't Really matter cause Dave walks in anyways."}

    elsif answerdoor.include?('no') && door == 1

        erb :answerdoorno, :locals => {:answerdoor => "You Decide not to answer the door, but it dosen't Really matter cause its the cops and the bust in."}            
        redirct to ('/police')

    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the sleep method before the erb render?

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sleep

Comment: elsif   answerdoor.include?('yes') && door == 1
    (ive tried it here)
    erb :answerdoor, :locals => {:answerdoor => "You Decide to get up and answer the door", :answerdoor2 => " Oh No its The cops." } (and here)
     redirect to ('/police')                                                                                                             and it just will wait the time and redirect but chow me my erb file im trying to see first

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want in Ruby. You should render your HTML where you could add some javascript or html to redirect after a second or more.

For example add this meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://example.com/" />
```

Where `1` is an amount of seconds